# Upload file to my google drive from anyone using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am new to google api. I am able to do this file upload from app script and any file which is uploaded through that script get stored to my drive only. 
But how to do this using javascript.
Example on google : https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js
shows how to do this but file gets uploaded to the same user's drive who is authorizing the app. How to restrict it to my drive only. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer is you cant with JavaScript.   The reason being is that JavaScript works with OAuth2 this requires that you ask the user permission to access your data.

If you want to have it access your drive account you would have to save the refreshtoken some place and then send that when ever the script was loaded.  JavaScript is client sided so anyone that checked the code on the page would then have all the information they needed to do what ever they wanted with your drive account.   Security wise that's a bad idea.

I recommend you look into using a server sided scripting language like PHP.  You might want to consider a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).  Note: everything will be owned by the service account so you will either have to give the Service account access to your Google Drive files or you will need to move your drive files to the Service account.

If you don't want the service account to have the files you could go with normal Oauth2 save the refresh token and then store it in the server sided code there wont be as much of security risk there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible with google picker? I was searching for my query and i found about google picker. It is also used for uploading files to drive. Does this have the same restriction

Comment: Google picker Uses oauth2 I think. So the users are going to access there data not yours.

Comment: Ok. I am using file upload in my code which will upload to only one shared google drive. It is easily achieved by app script but the problem is that i cannot use that script on my webpage. So i tried it with javscript.