# Uploading file to a single google drive from any user using a web interface

Tags: javascript, api, file-upload, google-drive-api

Working on a project for which I have to create a web-page where the user uploads a file which will go directly to my google drive. I've done lots of research on it and all I found is lots of links explaining "how the user can upload a file to his/her google drive using a web page" and according to my research Google apis are also available for this purpose only if that.
What I found in G APIs-
User's authentication is required with their mail-ID, and then they can upload the file to their drive anytime.
Help me on how a user, whenever opens the webpage and tries uploading any file, the file will go to my drive.
I'm working with javascript here and the API I was talking about - [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js).

Comment: You won't be able to do this with JavaScript because it uses OAuth2, which requires you to ask for the user's permission to access your data.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23904870/4241842

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, what you want to do is:

1. Your website visitor clicks on a file upload form on your website and selects a file from his local computer.
2. The file is uploaded and sent to your Google Drive.

For this purpose, you can use the CloudWok file-upload-to-cloud embed widget which you can copy and paste into the HTML code of your website: http://developers.cloudwok.com