# Upload Files to GOOGLE DRIVE without user authentication only when form submitted in LARAVEL OR AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, google-drive-api

I want to use Google Drive  to store my application files without user authentication. I have already seen  [Use Google Drive API with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778296/use-google-drive-api-with-laravel/24798103#24798103) but the answers do not match with my needs.

I have also tried an ajax post request when form submitted.

I want to know how do I get this request that I have found in Google Drive documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads .

1. POST /upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
2. Host: www.googleapis.com
3. Content-Type: image/jpeg
4. Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_file
5. Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token

JPEG data

Comment: i dont think they will allow it without auth otherwise anyone could upload to anyones account when they want, the auth is there to allow access?? Hence the `Bearer your_auth_token` so you will need to do the auth during the ajax call etc before uploading.

Comment: yes I agree , I am still newbie of ajax request , can you please help me ?

Comment: all i can recommend is searching for laravel / php and goole drive api, as you will need to set up secret keys etc and use somethign like guzzle to connect...

Comment: ok thanks , I think it is impossible to get all uploaded data centralized in one google drive account ? is that right ? everyone can only upload to his own drive via the api .

Answer (score 0):

As have been mentioned in the comment and from [Daimto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903378/upload-file-to-my-google-drive-from-anyone-using-javascript/23904870#23904870), Google Drive (and other SaaS tools) requires authentication, for security purposes.

Try the [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php) in Drive API v3. The basic structure is already there.

For an actual example of uploading a file using the API, this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707891/google-drive-php-api-simple-file-upload/25715084) might help:

```
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId('<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>');
$client->setClientSecret('<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>');
$client->setRedirectUri('<YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI>');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));

session_start();

if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])) {
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

//Insert a file
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle(uniqid().'.jpg');
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$file->setMimeType('image/jpeg');

$data = file_get_contents('a.jpg');

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
'data' => $data,
'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
'uploadType' => 'multipart'
));

print_r($createdFile);

} else {
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
exit();
}
```

There's also a [google/google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) in Github. The guide might offer you insight as well.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, all files and folders in Google Drive must have an authenticated user as an owner. Anyway, it should be possible to wrap around your solution with a "proxy" which uploads the file using your own account or a Google Service Account.

You will present a web page to your end user where anonymous access is allowed, then after getting the data uploaded, you will call the API in the background with your own account or a Google Service Account.